# Anachronistic equivalent for regional disparity

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

Is there an equivalent term to anachronistic when referring to regional disparities between concepts rather than chronological ones?

Comment: Foreigner might fit

Answer (score 0):

How about "displaced"? Does that fit your requirements?